# Blazor radio button two-way binding not working on properties

Tags: c#, .net-core, radio-button, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am new to using Blazor, I am looking to use the two-way binding for the "checked" properties of a radio button.

I am displaying questions for a survey, what I want is that after selecting the response, it goes to the next questions and the radio button should be deselected but is not working.

This code is not doing anything

```
 questionOption.Selected = false;
 StateHasChanged();
```

and once I select the radio button, it gets selected for the rest of the questions.

This is my code:

```
@inject IQuestionService QuestionService;

@foreach (QuestionOption questionOption in QuestionOptions)
{
 <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">
        <input type="radio"
               class="form-check-input"
               @key="@("radioBtn" + questionOption.Id)"
               name="optradio"
               checked="@questionOption.Selected"
               value="@questionOption.OptionValue"
               @onclick="() => SelectionMade(questionOption)">
        @questionOption.OptionDescription
    </label>
  </div>
 }

@code {
[Parameter]
public List<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Store selected question option in the question object and call for a state change
/// </summary>
/// <param name="questionOption"></param>
private void SelectionMade(QuestionOption questionOption)
{
    //  State has been updated so call state changed to all registered objects
    QuestionService.OnQuestionOptionChange(questionOption);

    questionOption.Selected = false;
    StateHasChanged();
 }
}
```

the radio button appears deselected the first time then when I select one time I am not able to deselect it anymore.

Any help, please?
Thanks

Comment: This is normal built-in behaviour for Radio buttons, once selected you can't go back to 'none'

Comment: Ah, "next question". Not part of the code. Are the option.Id values unique over all questions?  Because then the @key should have solved this.